# Submitted App With Debugging Enabled, Should I Resubmit?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Right so I feel a bit foolish about this, but I've just realised I submitted my iOS phonegap app with debugging enabled!

I compiled the app with Phonegap Build and completely forgot I had the debug setting enabled. Could this be a problem and a reason for my app to be rejected?

Should I cancel this submission and re-submit a version with the debugging setting disabled? Or is there some little check in Phonegap Build which automatically disables debugging when the app has been compiled with a distribution key?

As far as I understand, if I resubmit then my app will be placed back at the beginning of the review process again (it's been 3/4 days since it was submitted)

Any knowledge of this would be appreciated!

**Update:**
I have now established that Phonegap Build does in fact still include the debugging script even when the app is compiled with a distribution cert. However all it does is inject one `script src` tag into the end of the `index.html` file, so hopefully Apple won't mind that? I'm not over a week into the review process and still waiting for Apple's decision so hopefully I'll know soon and update this post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after all that, my app was finally approved by Apple with the debugging script in it! So note to to all, it's not the end of the world if you were foolish enough to submit it with debugging enabled! Obviously I will remove it in my next version, but nice to know it won't cause your app to be rejected anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'd check with PGB to see if the debugging is still on.

It may cause it to be rejected but even if it doesn't I'd upload a new version. It usually takes 7 days for my apps and new version to be accepted. It's not a big deal.

Comment: I know the setting in PGB was still enabled, but I have seen with other app builders that debugging is only activated when a development signing key is detected, I've yet to find any mention of this with PGB but I can only hope it's the same. Normally I would just re-submit but because it's this far into the process and because I'm hoping to go live with it next week I think I'll just have to wait it out!